# How to expand and shrink two different div's with one hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have two divs that's are both width of 500px side by side. Then when you over one the the divs the hovered div expands to a width of 800px and the other div shrinks to a size of 200px.

Currently I have managed to make one of the divs expand but cannot work out how to make the other shrink at the same time.

```
$(function () { 
    $('.companybox1').hover(
        function () { 
            $(this).animate({ width: '+=300' }, 750, function () { }); 
        }, 
        function () { 
            $('.companybox1').animate({ width: '-=300' }, 750, function () { }); 
        }); 
});
```

Comment: @IsaacFife: Smells like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines. You can use smarter selectors than this one. (like for example getting the sibling-divs, etc).

```
$('.companybox1').hover(
    function () { 
        $(this).animate({ width: '+=300' }, 750, function () { }); 
        $('.companybox2').animate({ width: '-=300' }, 750, function () { });
    }
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
$('.companybox1').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({ width: '+=300' }, 750, function () { })
           .siblings()
           .animate({ width: '-=300' }, 750, function () { });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({ width: '-=300' }, 750, function () { })
           .siblings()
           .animate({ width: '+=300' }, 750, function () { });
})​
```

here a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub3Xt/)

Answer (score 0):

See this example.. is it helps?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZN8bq/

```
$(function(){

    $('.overable').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({ width: '+=300' }, 500);
        if($(this).hasClass('div1')){
            $('.div2').animate({ width: '-=300' }, 500);
        } else {
            $('.div1').animate({ width: '-=300' }, 500);
        }
    }, function(){
        $('.overable').animate({ width: '500px' }, 500);
    });

});​
```